# Empty user input

Tags: java

how can I give some print statement when user input is empty/blank.Here is my code so far where radius (r) is an argument.

```
package demo;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Circ{
    public static void main(String []args)
{   

        double area,r,circumference;
        System.out.println("enter the radius");
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        r=scan.nextDouble();

        if(r<0)
        {
            System.out.println("mismatch value");
            System.exit(0);
        }


        else{
            area=3.14*r*r;
            circumference=2*3.14*r;
            System.out.println("The area is " + area + "circumference is " + circumference); 
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `hasNextDouble()` to check whether a double exists in the stream. User cannot give *empty* input, it won't be accepted. Your program will wait until the user types *non-whitespace charater(s)* and then presses `enter`. If the input is *not* a `double`, then `InputMismatchException` will be thrown.

Comment: Hi how can I check for user input for double in above code.hasNextDouble didn't work for me..

Comment: You can't get empty space. . Use nextDouble() to read double value. . Or use nextLine() and parse the value as a double